# AWS S3 no longer return the "Location" URL in the new v3 API

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, localstack

I'm switching from the old AWS S3 v2 API to the new modular v3 API.

I'm doing testing using LocalStack.

Before i used this [upload](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#upload-property) method which returned the "Location" URL of the uploaded object.

In the new v3 API, i don't seem to get this URL back. I've tried both the [PutObjectCommand](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-s3/classes/putobjectcommand.html) from `client-s3` and the [Upload](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/modules/_aws_sdk_lib_storage.html) from `lib-storage`.

Do i have to build the URL myself or is there an API i can use?